# How can I tell if a variable is emty or not in selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I want to store the protocol used (http/https) in a variable, however internet explorer doesn't respond to window.location.protocol so for that case, the variable will be empty. In that case I'm ok to put https as default.
But how do I do that?

This is what I cooked up so far.

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>window.location.protocol</td>
    <td>HOST_PROTOCOL</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>if (${HOST_PROTOCOL}.equals("") { return "https" }</td>
    <td>HOST_PROTOCOL</td>
</tr>
```

So far, I found out how to use if properly:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>javascript{ if (storedVars['HOST_PROTOCOL'] !="http:" || storedVars['HOST_PROTOCOL'] !="https:") { alert() }  }</td>
    <td>HOST_PROTOCOL</td>
</tr>
```

Now, how to "return https" as result for the storeEval?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that the following works for my question

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>javascript{ if (window.location.protocol !="http:" || window.location.protocol !="https:") { storedVars['HOST_PROTOCOL']="https:";} else { storedVars['HOST_PROTOCOL']=window.location.protocol } ;true}</td>
    <td>x</td>
</tr>
```

where I first check if window.location.protocol is http or https.
If so, I fill my variable HOST_PROTOCOL with the value of window.location.protocol.
In all other cases I fill my variable with the value "https:"
And I return true to the javascript, passing the selenium commmand as green.

Comment: I'd say to do it slightly differently:    <td>javascript{ if ( window.location.protocol =="https:") { storedVars['HOST_PROTOCOL']="https:";} else { storedVars['HOST_PROTOCOL']="http:" } ;true}</td>

Comment: Hi DMart, thats a nice short version, thanks for it. Only thing with your solution is that no other protocols can be handled now.